# Setting a different height/width for a mobile site

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, height

I just created my portfolio, and want a full screen mobile site overlay to display saying 'coming soon' etc whenever my site is viewed on a mobile device.

I have tried this with media queries; however, for some reason the body height is being ignored. If you visit the site and inspect element, you can see that the site is still 300vw x 300vh.

```
html body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 300vh;
  width: 300vw;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

My website is 'https://nathan.work' if anyone wants to look in to the issue.

Maybe there's some way that when loaded on mobile, it takes the user to a completely different .html file? I'm unsure when it comes to mobile responsiveness.

Comment: why change the body and html size if you just want to place an overlay on top of it?  Also, your media query isn't working as your original selector is more specific than your media query - `html body` vs `body`

Comment: @Pete I wanted to change the size of the body because you're able to scroll below, and to the right of the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your site in particular, you can add `position:fixed` so wherever the user scrolls, the overlay follows.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I didn't think about this - Works great!